# My http server can only be accessed from localhost, but not from the outside ip

Tags: raspbian, apache-httpd

I setup my Raspberry Pi 1 with Raspbian to create a simple server. I can access the server from the localhost from within the Raspberry Pi only, but not using its IP either from the Raspberry Pi itself or from other computers on my network. netstat shows that the server is listening from the correct port (I tried both 80 and 8080) and I'm able to access the Raspberry Pi using the external IP using ssh and it can also be pinged from that address. It seems that the Raspberry Pi is blocking any access using the outside IP to anything other ssh and ping. Is there any firewall on the Raspbian that may be blocking it?

Comment: Well, at least your ISP (Internet Service Provider) is blocking you, to avoid you getting too popular and causing more traffic than what you are paying them. :)

Comment: perhaps your http server is set up to only listen on localhost - port is one thing, which interface is listening is another

Comment: `I'm able to access the Raspberry Pi using the external IP` does the pi have its own public IP address? or have you used port forwarding on the router (I'm assuming IPv4 of course)

Comment: How you have run your HTTP server? I mean, by which package? -- However, it's not a problem with raspberry pi. It's all about your configuration on a Linux box (Raspbian or whatever distribution on raspberry pi on PC, etc.).

Comment: *Is there any firewall on the Raspbian that may be blocking it?* -- No. Use `nmap -p 80 x.x.x.x` from outside on another computer to check out is it accessible. The `x.x.x.x` can be the local IP address of raspberry pi on the local network OR the valid IP address that you got from ISP.

Comment: For what do you use port 8080?

Comment: @tlfong01 I'm not even accessing from outside my ISP. This is all within my local network.

Comment: @JaromandaX It is using the IP given by the router. As of now I'm only trying to access my serve from my local network,

Comment: @M.Rostami I'm using apache. I also tried sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80 with the same results (can access from localhost, but not the 192.168.1.14 IP that the router gave to the board, not even from the board itself.). I used nmap and it shows that the ports 80 and 8080 are closed, but 22 is open.

Comment: @Ingo A Apache webserver.

Comment: An Apache webserver by default only listens on one port 80. So it is still unclear for what port 8080 is used.

Comment: @Gabriel Diego, my apologies not reading your question carefully. Cheers.

Comment: @Ingo I only used the port 8080 with the python simple server, just to test it.

Comment: @tlfong01 no worries :-)

Comment: @GabrielDiego So, if the port is Closed (and is not Filtred), it means that the firewall is not blocking (the port is open but the OS not using).